# Can I restore previous IntelliJ IDEA "Delete to Word End" behavior to delete leading whitespace on the next line?

Tags: intellij-idea, ide, keyboard-shortcuts

Until somewhat recently, using the "Delete to Word End" functionality in IntelliJ IDEA (macOS keyboard shortcut: <kbd>⌥</kbd><kbd>⌦</kbd>) would delete through the end of the current line as well as any leading whitespace on the next line before the first word:

```
Line 1
   Line 2
```

=>

```
Line1Line2
```

This changed within the last year or two to keep the leading whitespace from the next line:

```
Line 1
   Line 2
```

=>

```
Line1   Line2
```

I much prefer the previous behavior.  While cleaning up code for readability, I'll often pull code that is split across multiple lines onto one line using this functionality.  What was previously one set of keystrokes is now two (I need to use the "Delete to Word End" key combination twice).  What's worse, if the next line happens to not have leading whitespace, I have to override the muscle memory and only type the shortcut once, or else I'll delete part or all of the code on the following line.

As a minimalistic yet realistic example, I might use this behavior to do the following code transformation:

```java
  List<String> myList = otherList.stream()
      .map(this::aMethod)
      .toList();
```

=>

```java
  List<String> myList = otherList.stream()
      .map(this::aMethod).toList();
```

I don't know what version specifically the change occurred, but I have a version of IntelliJ IDEA from 2016 which has the old functionality, and one 2021 with the new functionality.  I think the change happened in 2020 or 2021.

Is there a way to revert the behavior to the previous functionality (or perhaps an equivalent functionality under a different name)?

Comment: Try "Edit -> Join Lines"? Your carret can be at any position at the current line (Line1) to join it with the next line.

Comment: @IUSR Thanks, I was unfamiliar with that.  Though it's not _quite_ the same as what I'm looking for, as it appears to join the lines with a single space.

Comment: That's strange. I was aware of such behavior in many editors, so I specifically tried in my IDEA and there was no space in between :D What's the version of your IDEA?

Comment: @IUSR Wow, it appears to be very context-aware.  I tested it in a `.txt` file, which adds the space.  When I use it in a Java file before a line that starts with a `.` (such as the "realistic example" in my question), it joins the lines without a space.  And if the split line is Java string concatenation (`System.out.println("A" +<newline>    "B");`) it concatenates it into a single string (`System.out.println("AB");`).

Comment: Yes, exactly. I assumed you meant Java source files, so I also tested on a Java file. As for the code snippet you added in the question, I had no problem achieving the goal you intended with "Edit -> Join Lines". Is it same helpful with this for you or does it still insist inserting a space in between?

Comment: @IUSR Yeah, that pretty much achieves the goal for my most common use cases, thanks!

Comment: Nice! Glad it works. yw :)

Comment: @IUSR I'll probably expand that into a full answer at some point, unless you want to.

Comment: Please go ahead. Thanks for the offer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While it's not exactly the same functionality, the `Join Lines` action (<kbd>⌃</kbd><kbd>⇧</kbd><kbd>J</kbd> on macOS) accomplishes the same goal in many cases.  Regardless of where the caret is on the current line, it joins the current line to the next line, in context-sensitive ways.

For the given Java method call example, it has exactly the intended behavior of moving the method call to the current line without any spaces:

```java
  List<String> myList = otherList.stream()
      .map(this::aMethod)
      .toList();
```

=>

```java
  List<String> myList = otherList.stream()
      .map(this::aMethod).toList();
```

For a concatenated Java string split over the two lines, it will remove the string concatenation operator, combining the two strings into one:

```java
System.out.println("A" +
    "B");
```

=>

```java
System.out.println("AB");
```

In a plain text file, it will combine the lines, with a single space before the non-space text of the second line:

```
Line 1
   Line 2
```

=>

```
Line 1 Line 2
```

Comment: Thanks to @IUSR for pointing out this functionality in a
 [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73550521#comment129882976_73550521)